How to Efficiently Profile Data Using Dask in Parallel with Kubernetes Cluster
I'm seeking guidance on efficiently profiling data using Dask within a Kubernetes cluster. My data sources include data lakes and file systems like S3. Profiling tasks entail generating various artifacts such as bar plots, value distributions, heat maps, frequent values, duplicates, inferring data types, and identifying valid and invalid values.
I've opted to use Dask to lazily load the DataFrame, either from SQL tables (dask.read_sql_table) or CSV files (dask.read_csv). Once the DataFrame is loaded, I aim to execute multiple profiling tasks in parallel.
However, I'm unsure about how Dask will manage the computation when passing the Dask DataFrame to these parallel tasks, especially if the DataFrame has multiple partitions. My concern is whether Dask can effectively handle the computation of tasks and DataFrame concurrently.
Here's a snippet of the code structure I'm considering:
df = dask.read_sql_table(arguments)

future1 = dask_client.submit(generate_bar_plot_for_each_column, df)
future2 = dask_client.submit(generate_heat_map, df)
future3 = dask_client.submit(generate_value_distribution_for_each_column, df)
future4 = dask_client.submit(generate_mean_median_mode, df)
future5 = dask_client.submit(generate_frequent_value_for_each_column, df)
future6 = dask_client.submit(generate_duplicates, df)
# Additional profiling tasks...


Can Dask effectively manage the computation of tasks and DataFrame simultaneously, particularly when dealing with a DataFrame containing multiple partitions? Any insights or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Hi, the real question is how big are your Dataframes? If they fit in memory, just use Pandas, and optionnaly Dask to submit several computations on the Pandas Dataframe. If they are to big, I would recommend to launch the computations on Dask Dataframe sequentially. What you propose is possible, but a lot more complex to handle.
